# Difference between ubuntu and ARM Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, arm

1. What is the difference between normal Ubuntu and ARM Ubuntu. Can i run all the application which 
   are  running under normal Ubuntu in a ARM Ubuntu also ?
2. Is the Ubuntu update will happen automatically ?

Applications like torrent down-loader, File sharing .

I am looking to run a home server in a low cast , low power, low processing power and does normal operations like occasional file sharing and manage centralized storage and running 24/7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ARM Ubuntu according http://www.ubuntu.com/download/arm is for ARM-based systems only. It supports Calxeda ECX-1000 and Marvell Armadaxp (12.04 LTS only) production boards.
2. Ubuntu update will not happen automatically. It checks if there is new updates automatically but never will update without yours permission. Security updates can be enabled to be updated automatically. For this you need to install unattended-upgrades:

   ```
     sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
     sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades
   ```

If you want to have home server - install [Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server). It's reliable and the most important free. It will do all your detailed operations like file sharing and more.

Answer (score 0):

I bought the Raspberry Pi and have Raspian installed. Based on that i am trying to answer my own question, hope it may help some body.

The ARM version will almost look a like normal OS. But still this is not same as actual OS. Said that the objective of having low cost , low power consuming home server is very much possible with Raspian (which is a derivate of Debian). There are n-number of tutorial available in the internet to set up home server. I got the hardware and OS ready now , building up my home server now.

Comment: "But still this is not same as actual OS" - untrue.  An operating system is an operating system, and this clearly is one.  Perhaps you meant to say that it is not quite the same as a "Desktop" OS or something like that.